# customize sorted ordered by reverse Java

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, stream, reverse

I have the following list:

```
List<String> courses = List.of("Spring", "Spring Boot", "API", "Microservices",
            "AWS", "PCF", "Azure", "Docker", "Kubernetes");
```

I want to sort this list by the course.length(), but it has to be reversed. This is the excpected output:

```
Microservices
Spring Boot
Kubernetes
Docker
Spring
Azure
PCF
AWS
API
```

This is the line of code that I'm working on, but it does not work:

```
courses.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(word -> word.length()).reversed())
```

I really appreciate if someone can give a hand.

Comment: What is expected when the words have same length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick we can use here is to use the negative value of the string length when sorting:

```java
List<String> courses = List.of("Spring", "Spring Boot", "API", "Microservices",
    "AWS", "PCF", "Azure", "Docker", "Kubernetes");
courses = courses.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(word -> -1.0*word.length())).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(courses);
```

This prints:

```
[Microservices, Spring Boot, Kubernetes, Spring, Docker, Azure, API, AWS, PCF]
```

Comment: Why did you use `comparing` and not `comparingInt`? If we take a careful look, the words with same length are sorted alphabetically in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Reversed returns an object of type `Object`. You'll need a cast:

```java
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> courses = List.of("Spring", "Spring Boot", "API", "Microservices", "AWS", "PCF", "Azure", "Docker", "Kubernetes");

    courses = courses.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> ((String) x).length()).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.toString())).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    courses.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you sort by the descending length, so that you can avoid the costly `reversed()` step in your stream?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, if you mean using -1 like you did, how can we get both the length as well as the alphabetical order in case the length is same, reversed?